# how should I write a test that proves or disproves the statements made and store the results of those tests in variables?

Tags: javascript

This is just a practice problem and I just wanted to know how it's done. I've tried a thing on my own but to no avail on how to make it work.

this is the script:

```
<script>
// Statement 1: The elephant weights less than the mouse
let eleWeight = 1000;
let mouseWeight = 2;

// Statement 2: The Ostrich is taller than the duck
let ostrichHeight = 2;
let duckHeight = 0.3;

// Statement 3: The two passwords match
let pwd1 = 'stromboli';
let pwd2 = 'stROmBoLi'

let weightComparison;
let heightComparison;
let pwdMatch;

const section = document.querySelector('section');

let para1 = document.createElement('p');
let para2 = document.createElement('p');
let para3 = document.createElement('p');

let weightTest = weightComparison ? 'True — elephants weight less than mice!?' : 'False — of course an elephant is heavier than a mouse!';
let heightTest = heightComparison ? 'True — an ostrich is indeed taller than a duck!' : 'False — apparently a duck is taller than an ostrich!?';
let pwdTest = pwdMatch ? 'True — the passwords match.' : 'False — the passwords do not match; please check them';

para1.textContent = weightTest;
section.appendChild(para1);
para2.textContent = heightTest;
section.appendChild(para2);
para3.textContent = pwdTest;
section.appendChild(para3);
```

I've tried:

```
let weightComparison = `${eleWeight > mouseWeight}`;
let heightComparison = `${ostrichHeight > duckHeight}`;
let pwdMatch = `${pwd1 !== pwd2}`;
```

doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens and what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Why to you use template literals, converting the result to string data type? Just do `weightComparison = eleWeight > mouseWeight`, which will assign a boolean value (true or false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should directly assign the result of the comparison instead of using strings.

Also based on the labels the `weightComparison` and `pwdMatch` should be reversed.

```js
// Statement 1: The elephant weights less than the mouse
let eleWeight = 1000;
let mouseWeight = 2;

// Statement 2: The Ostrich is taller than the duck
let ostrichHeight = 2;
let duckHeight = 0.3;

// Statement 3: The two passwords match
let pwd1 = 'stromboli';
let pwd2 = 'stROmBoLi'

let weightComparison = eleWeight < mouseWeight;
let heightComparison = ostrichHeight > duckHeight;
let pwdMatch = pwd1 === pwd2;

const section = document.querySelector('section');

let para1 = document.createElement('p');
let para2 = document.createElement('p');
let para3 = document.createElement('p');

let weightTest = weightComparison ? 'True — elephants weight less than mice!?' : 'False — of course an elephant is heavier than a mouse!';
let heightTest = heightComparison ? 'True — an ostrich is indeed taller than a duck!' : 'False — apparently a duck is taller than an ostrich!?';
let pwdTest = pwdMatch ? 'True — the passwords match.' : 'False — the passwords do not match; please check them';

para1.textContent = weightTest;
section.appendChild(para1);
para2.textContent = heightTest;
section.appendChild(para2);
para3.textContent = pwdTest;
section.appendChild(para3);
```

```html
<section></section>
```